# Fastet way to get position of all newlines in a string

Tags: python, search

I am writing a search function to find all occurrences of a pattern in a string. One of the outputs I need is the position on the current line of the match. To do this I am finding all the locations of the newlines and using the match position along with the newline position to get the line position. What I am having issues with is getting the newline positions. Because I am regularly going to be dealing with large files, I need to be as efficient as possible. I have tried several different approaches to this problem. The first was:

```
_newline_positions = []
for _index, _char in enumerate(string):
    if _char == "\n":
        _newline_positions.append(_index)
```

It was by far the slowest and took nearly 80% percent of the run-time just for this part.

Next I tried this, which is similar to how I actually implemented the search for the pattern.

```
    _newline_positions = []
    while _position < len(string):
        _position = string.find("\n", _position)
        if _position != -1:
            _newline_positions.append(_position)
        else:
            break
        _position += 1
```

It was more efficient than the first attempt but it only reduced the percentage of time taken by about 20%, to around 60%.

Finally I tried a solution I found using regex:

```
_newline_positions = [match.start() for match in re.finditer("\n", string)]
```

Its the shortest and most efficient taking only 40% of the search time, but when compared to everything else in the search function it is still by far the most time intensive part.

Is there any other way to do this that is faster, or is this type of regex solution the most efficient for this problem?

Comment: Why, oh why, are you putting a leading underscore in front of your variable names? Is ... do you do it to make me angry :)

Comment: If you only need the position *on the current line*, and you're dealing with files... why are you performing your search over the entire file, held in memory all at once, instead of just iterating over the lines and searching each line?

Comment: If you can afford writing a C extension for this (or probably even just using cython) the equivalent to the first solution is going to be the fastest, and I expect a speedup between 20 and 100 times compared to the Python equivalent.

Comment: @MatteoItalia yeah, that is my guess too. I don't think there will be a Python solution that will be faster than the regex... Should be relatively straightforward in Cython.

Comment: @user2357112 The problem is that I need the absolute position as well, which I now see that I neglected to mention. I apologize about that. However, even if I didn't wouldn't splitting a large file be very slow, or am I misinterpreting your suggestion?

Comment: @ChrisBeaulieu: While I don't know how fast it is in absolute terms, I think it's likely you're misinterpreting my suggestion. I'm suggesting to do `for line in file:` instead of `file.read()`.

Comment: Perhaps if your files are encoded simply, i.e. `ascii`, you can load the file into a `numpy` array and take advantage of the speed there?

Answer (score 1):

This comes in about twice as fast as the regexes in my test:

```
with open(file) as f:
  newline_positions = [-1]
  for v in f:
     newline_positions.append(newline_positions[-1]+len(v))
  print(newline_positions[1:])
```

It does require an iteration over all the lines in your file, which may or may not be useful to you.

Comment: I tried this but it was slower in my case, by about 2x. Maybe I need to change the profiling method I have been using...

Comment: After a little more work, I found that while the method you gave didnt appear faster it provided me with enough informaiton to remove most of my code, turning my complex search into a pretty simple two loop solution. Overall, I got about a 5x increase on large files compared to my old solution.

Comment: It is probably my testing method that need to change.  Small sample size in small file.

Answer (score 0):

Regex is most likely to be the fastest since the bulk of the "work" is being done in compiled C code. The other options described are pure python, and looping in Python is a lot slower than looping in C.